# Spring boot reference file location from resources in properties file

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot application using Google Pub Sub API. I need to inject Google credentials and other properties using file `credentials.json`. I put the file in my `src/main/resources` (otherwise, it will not put the file in the built jar) like this:

```
spring.cloud.gcp.credentials.location=file:src/main/resources/credentials.json
```

However, when I build the jar, this file is placed in the root directory and this path is no longer valid. So I am able to run my application from Eclipse, since by the that time, the file is still in my resources directory but I can't run it as a standalone jar after built because the path is suddently just `file:credentials.json`.

Is there some easy way how to specify the path as relative so it works both in IDE and when running my jar? I can inject the path through env. variables but I would do so only if absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you use the `classpath` prefix then Spring will look for the file on your classapth.

If you put the file in `src/main/resources` then Maven will, by default, copy it to the root of your classpath and it will then be addressable as follows:

```
spring.cloud.gcp.credentials.location=classpath:credentials.json
```

This should hold true whether ...

- You are running in your IDE; your IDE's Maven integration will copy the file from `src/main/resources` to the root of your classpath - typically `target/classes`
- You are running a built JAR; Maven will copy the file from `src/main/resources` to the root of your JAR

Comment: I was about to write just that, on top of that, you can also define the path through a system property ex. -Dmy.credentials.path=/my/nice/path/credentials.json and access it there or, last but not least, you can use a profile.

Comment: Thank you. Just what I needed!